# Variables being set but if statement not working in tkinter for python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make this app real quick for fun but when I try using a specific if statement, it doesn't follow through. Even though the values needed for it is present.

Here is the code for logging in and etc:

```py
from tkinter import *
import json, threading, time
window = Tk()
window.title("MikuOS")
window.geometry('350x200')
global loggedin
loggedin = False
a = ''
if 'false' not in open('users.json', 'r').read():
    lbl = Label(window, text="Welcome to MikuOS! MikuOS is in alpha.\nPlease enter a new password: ")
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    txt = Entry(window,width=15)
    txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def clicked():
        json.dump({'users':{'password':txt.get(), 'firsttime':False}}, open('users.json', 'w'))
        lbl.destroy()
        txt.destroy()
        btn.destroy()
    btn = Button(window, text="entr", command=clicked)
    btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

elif 'false' in open('users.json', 'r').read() and loggedin != True:
    lbl = Label(window, text="Welcome to mikuOS!\nPlease enter your password to continue. ")
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    def clicked():
        if txt.get() == json.load(open('users.json', 'r'))['users']['password']:
            loggedin = True
            lbl.destroy()
            txt.destroy()
            btn.destroy()
            print(loggedin)
    txt = Entry(window,width=15)
    txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
    btn = Button(window, text='enter', command=clicked)
    btn.grid(column=1, row=1)

print(loggedin)

if loggedin == True:
    print(loggedin)
    def key_pressedo(event):
        global a
        a += 'o'
        def olbld():
            olbl.destroy()
        if 'owo' in a:
            a =''
            olbl = Label(window, text="OwO mode activated! (it only displays this)")
            olbl.grid(column=0,row=0)
            olbl.after(5000, olbld)
        print(a)
    def key_pressedw(event):
        global a
        a+='w'
    print(a)
    window.bind("o",key_pressedo)
    window.bind("w",key_pressedw)

window.mainloop()
```

No errors.
Here is some totally extra details in order for me to add the whole code so people can actually help me because stackoverflow is just annoying when it comes to preventing people from doing that but alright I understand why anyways this should be the end of this bye bye anyways I hope you can help me/get helped by this question.

Comment: Why is the elif statement comes before the if?

Comment: @Onur There was some code in it that I didn't include. It isn't needed for now, but I do assign the "loggedin" variable at the start of the code to prevent any extra errors.

Comment: Can I ask where do you assign loggedin and what is the value of it

Comment: I assign it after I set the needed variables for tk to work, such as window, window title and window geometry. Which I set the variable to be global before I assign the value which I set the value to False.

Comment: @Onur Also, sorry for the late response but ^^

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: What is the output of the line `print(loggedin)`? I think it should be `False` and so the code inside the followed `if` statement should not be executed.

Comment: Please give us a little bigger block of code, to see what the variables are assigned to and what is the code you have written before the `elif` statement

Comment: @InfoDaneMent It will not let me show all of the code without putting "extra details" but sure I'll try.

Comment: If the the value of `loggedin` is false, then the code won't process the parts inside the if statement. Also sorry for the late reply, I had some business to do.

Comment: Is fine but, when I log in I have it so that it sets logged in to True @Onur

Comment: If you don't get an error message, there must be a logic error which doesn't effect the program but it does not do the intended. I'll need a brief explanation of what are you trying to achieve and where?

Comment: @Onur I done explained that in the description.

Comment: **I am trying to make this app real quick for fun but when I try using a specific if statement, it doesn't follow through. Even though the values needed for it is present.** Is not really an explanation of what you're trying to do. It'd be better to explain what you try to achieve within the if statement.

Comment: I just saw something, I'm not really sure if this'll work but try changing `def olbld():` to `def olbld(event):`

Comment: You need to understand what ___event-driven programming___ is.

Comment: @Onur Nope, it didn't work.

Comment: Also, @acw1668 mind explaining to me what that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is going back to `loggedin = False` constantly which causes it to reset to False and not keep it all True, you can fix this by putting the `loggedin = False` before the imports.